# Best algorithm for converting real number between 0 and 1 to index

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Suppose x is a real number between 0 and 1

If n = 2 there are two fractions ranges 0 to 0.5 and 0.5 to 1

If n = 3 there are three fractions ranges 0 to 0.33, 0.33 to 0.66 and 0.66 to 1

I want to know the most efficient algorithm that tells which fraction x belongs to.

If x = 0.2 and n = 3, x belongs to first fraction so index is 0

If x = 0.4 and n = 3, x belongs to second fraction so index is 1

Here's the python 3 code which has O(N) complexity.

```
def index(x, n):
  for i in range(0, n):
    if i/n <= x and x <= (i + 1)/n:
      return i
```

I want to know if there is a better algorithm may be with constant time?

Edit: I did not explicitly said before but both 0 and 1 is a legit value for x and result should be n - 1 when x = 1

Comment: Multiply by n?.

Comment: If `n=2`, where do `x=0`, `x=0.5` an `x=1` (exactly) belong?

Comment: @n.m. If x = 0 return value is 0, x = 1 return value is 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just multiply both numbers and cut the decimal place:

```
def index(x, n):
    return int(x*n)
```

Complexity is O(1)

Comment: Note: If `x == 1`, then this will result in `n`, which will yield an `IndexError` if actually used for indexing. Can easily be fixed using e.g. `min`, though.

Comment: @tobias_k yielding IndexError is totally correct and works as designed. Or what would you expect in that case?

Comment: Well, for a list `[1,2,3,4]`, I would expect  `x==1` to yield `4`, i.e. the last value in the list.

Comment: You mean you would expect 3? The function is returning the index, not the element. Although yielding the last index would not make any sense.

Comment: @miindlek It should be n - 1 when x == 1, sorry I did not mentioned explicitly about that situation.

Comment: Yes, I meant the element `4`, at index `3`. Sorry, very unclear example.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do the following:

```
def index(x,n):
    return (10*x // n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
import math

def index(x, n):
    return math.ceil(x*n)
```